# Hacer un commit de archivos referenciados dentro de un archivo

Tags: git, git-commit

Supongamos que tengo un archivo: `Listadearchivos` que contiene una lista de archivos que quiero commitear, porque no me interesa commitear todos los archivos de mi proyecto, sino solo los contenidos en `Listadearchivos`
¿Hay algún comando con el que pueda especificar hacer commits de los archivos referenciados dentro de un archivo (en este caso dicho archivo es `Listadearchivos`)?

Answer (score 1):

En realidad tienes la opción inversa: en el archivo .gitignore puedes especificar los archivos que NO quieras incluir en el commit

Answer (score 0):

Vaya...parece que git no da esa opción. Lo único que se me ocurre es hacer un script en bash que pasándole un fichero con sus nombres y sus rutas me vaya haciendo un `git add rutaarchivo/nombrearchivo`, justo antes de hacer el commit.

Comment: Y un `git add \`cat Listadearchivos\`` ? en todo caso, mejor usar `.gitignore` como te dice @David